# required fields should only be needed upon element display

Tags: javascript, html, required

I have a form where a user is asked if he has an authorized representative in form of a radio button. If the user choose the 'yes' option, it will show more fields about the representative and it has a required input 'representative email'.

Is there a way for it to be only needed when the user choose the yes option? The form is not submitting because it keeps finding the value of this required field if the user chooses the 'no option'.

```
<form>

<div class="onBehalfOf">
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Radio" id="yes" value="Yes">
<label for="yes"> Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="Radio" id="no" value="No">
<label for="no"> No</label>
</div>

<div class="authorizedRep">
Email:
<input type="email" required />
</div>

<input type="submit" label="submit" />

</form>
```

[js Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rdfLcvdg/2/)

Comment: It looks like you never accept answers on your questions. This will put people off and make it less likely that you get an answer. You should consider accepting the answer which has solved your problem on past and future questions. For reference, this is the tick on submitted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small change you can toggle the `required` attribute on the email input when you show/hide the fields. You just need to add the appropriate `emailInput` class to the element.

```
$('.onBehalfOf input:radio').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'No') {
    if ($('.authorizedRep').hasClass("hide")) {

    } else {
      $('.authorizedRep').addClass("hide");
      $('.emailInput').removeAttr('required');
    }
  }

  if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Yes') {
    $('.authorizedRep').removeClass("hide");
    $('.emailInput').attr('required');
  }
});
```

Comment: I was actually thinking of the same thing but was looking for something like an explanation as to why this things happen or if there's a way to continue through the form without removing the required attrib. Thanks for confirming what I had in mind.

Comment: The form will parse the required attribute no matter what, the only way really is to remove it, as you suspected. It would be confusing if there were obscure ways to enable and disable mandatory fields in forms.